# PHP,preg_match,Regular Expression. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Here is the pattern that I want to match:

```
<div class="class">
<a href="http://www.example.com/something"> I want to be able to capture this text</a>
<span class="ptBrand">
```

This is what I am doing:

```
$pattern='{<div class="productTitle">[\n]<((https?|ftp|gopher|telnet|file|notes|ms-help):((//)|(\\\\))+[\w\d:#@%/;$()~_?\+-=\\\.&]*)>([^\n]*)</a>[\n]<span class="ptBrand">}';

preg_match($pattern, $data, $matches,PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

print_r($matches);
```

It prints:

Array ( )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a general rule, regular expressions are a really poor means of parsing HTML. They're unreliable and tend to end up being really complicated. A far more robust solution is to use an HTML parser. See [Parse HTML With PHP And DOM](http://www.phpro.org/examples/Parse-HTML-With-PHP-And-DOM.html).

As for your expression, I don't see `<div class="productTitle"` anywhere in the source so I'd start there. Likewise you're trying to parse a URL but there's no mention of the anchor tag (either directly or through a sufficient wildcard) so it'll fail there too. Basically that expression doesn't look anything like the HTML you're trying to parse.

Answer (score 1):

... Or this:

```
preg_match('/\s*([^>]+)\s*<\/a/',$string,$match);
```

Trims it too.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern:

`/<div class="class">\s*<a href=\"([^"]+)\">([^<]+)</a>/m`

Would get the link and text roughly, but using the DOM library would be a much better method.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<a href=".*?">([\s\S]*?)</a>
```